# How to get 'user_impersonation' scope for a token

Tags: azure-active-directory, msal.js

I create an application in Azure Active directory via Azure portal. And I have 'Request API permission' for 'user_impersonation'.

[image]

In my JS code which uses msal.js library, I tried requested token using this scope, but I don't get any token back.

```
   scopes: ["user_impersonation"]
```

But if I use

```
scopes: ["User.Read"]
```

or

```
scopes: [.default]
```

I get a token back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue getting the same situation like you as `user_impersonation` scope name could be anything you because it is a custom scope, as long as your code check for that same scope name that you created.

Conclude from this ***[github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop/issues/36)*** discussion, there might be still sync issue from MS end. You can raise a **GITHUB** request for the same or you can reach out to ***[AzureSuport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request)*** Team also.

`scope` is `Application ID URI` from Expose an API followed by `/.default`. Without `/.default` you will get an error like:

[image]

Tried with ***[OAuth2 permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-v1-app-scopes)*** scopes with changing the **[Application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#manifest-reference)** but didn’t help.

To get this working, you would either have to use **./default**, or if trying to specify specific permission, it has to be **application permission** for it to work with **Client_Credentials flow**.

[image]

For me I am not able to give `application permission` for my custom scope which I have created in `Exposed API` and with `delegated permission` getting the same error. Try if you can give `application permission`.

[image]

Comment: Be carefull: You misspelled `user_impersonation` twice in different ways, not sure if your tests are valid: once as `user_imporsonation` (`o` for `a`) and once as `user_impersonantion` (additional `n`).

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. I have updated the same.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to try with Postman like below to get exact error. The steps I followed are,

1. Created an API application, registered in AD, it automatically added user_impersonation scope in 'Expose an API'.
2. Registered another App in AD, went to API permissions, searched for the API app and selected with 'user_impersonation' scope.
3. Granted admin consent
4. In postMan I was able to generate the access_token, verified that it has scope 'user_impersonation' to the API app. (Remember that it works with 'password' grant flow only, with client_credentials flow, we can't generate token for 'user_impersonation' scope)
5. Finally was able to access the API app with that bearer token.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-linux

[Exposing API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE57r.png)

[Searching for API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgpGJ.png)

[Add permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiij6.png)